# iOS 5 upgrade deleted calendar from iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone

I managed to go into iTunes and change some settings for the calendar and was able to recover some of my calendar for my iPhone but not all of my events are on there.  And my iPad calender has nothing on it!  My iPhone has an extra calendar which is the name of my email address and my iPad dosent give me an option for this calendar which is why I think it's blank.  So I need to know what my settings should be to find my original calendar that i had on my iPhone?

Comment: This won't help right now, but in the near future you should look into syncing your calendars (and other supported data) with iCloud, Gmail, Exchange, etc. on iOS.

Comment: I think the extra calendar might be evidence that she's got iCloud or mobileme working, maybe set up incorrectly on multiple devices.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do a full restore from the backup at iTunes should have made before upgrading? Right click on iPhone in iTunes (device window on left) and hit restore from backup

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me: I seemed to have lost all my info from my calendar after the upgrade. But it turned out to just not getting displayed any longer:

- Go to Settings/Mail, Contacts, Calendar
- In the Calendar section click "Default Calendar" and put a checkmark next to "Home" (or whichever calendar you want to see).
- Switch to the Calendar app.

I got all my data back! I hope it helps.